# Django: one-to-many relationship and reverse lookup

Tags: django, one-to-many, reverse-lookup

i have a Problem which i am unsure what the most django/pythonic way to solve it would be.
I have the following models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ord_someinformation = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Articles(models.Model):
    myFK = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    detail_article= models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

so every Order can have multiple Order_Details think about it like a shopping basket where i have an Order and within it i have multiple articles.

I want to iterate over the orders and the articles within the template. I thought about something like.

```
myOrder = Order.objects.("" i have no idea what to put here "")
```

within the template i thought about something like this:

```
{% for order in myOrder %}
    {{ order.ord_someinformation }}
    {% for articles in order.articles %}
        {{ detail_article }}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

is this possible?
If so how ?

Comment: thanks i changed myOrder = Order.objects.("" i have no idea what to put here "") to myOrder = Order.objects.("" You really have no idea. "") but it didnt work either ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you think you need to put anything there. You just want to send all the orders to the template, then iterate through them their articles there.

```
myOrder = Order.objects.all()
```

...

```
{% for order in myOrder %}
    {{ order.ord_someinformation }}
    {% for article in order.articles_set.all %}
        {{ article.detail_article }}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didnt knew "{% for article in order.articles_set.all %}" that something like _set exists. Amazing.